# Able to perform Action even after Onclick button is disabled

Tags: visualforce

I am using `styleClass` to disable the button. In UI it is showing as disabled. But when I click on the button, I am able to perform an action. Please suggest me a solution.

```
<apex:commandButton
    id="canceldone"
    value="Cancel"
    onclick="OpenModel();return false;"
    styleClass="searchClass ordervalue btn btn-primary disabled {!IF( Industry == 'Enterprise','','sectionHeader')}"
    rerender="" >
</apex:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it as a style, set the `disabled` property.

```
<apex:commandButton id="canceldone" value="Cancel" 
      onclick="OpenModel();return false;"
      styleClass="searchClass ordervalue btn btn-primary"
      disabled="{!IF( Industry == 'Enterprise', True, False)}" 
      rerender="" >
</apex:commandButton>
```

You could ALSO set the disabled style too if you wanted to add some extra disabled styles.

Comment: Ah yes, copy paste error on my part - the main thing was to set the attribute not the style - I've corrected.